# JasperReport printing repeated values even when set not to

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I am combining an sql column and using the group count to print out only one line for combined items. However I'm getting this result:

[image]

Here's my code: (sorry if it's messy)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TableReceipt" pageWidth="225" pageHeight="800" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="195" leftMargin="5" rightMargin="25" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="516cb110-18eb-4a7a-865b-66c019f5be1a">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.9965000000000035"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="ticketId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[2]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="isSale" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[false]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="endTicket" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[false]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    t.TICKET_ITEM_ID,
    TICKET_ITEM_DESC,
    TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL,
    ticket.TICKET_ID,
    TICKET_CUSTOMER_NAME,
    TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL,
    TICKET_TOTAL_TAX,
    TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER
FROM
    ticket_item AS t,
    ticket
WHERE
    t.TICKET_ID = $P{ticketId}
AND
    ticket.TICKET_ID = $P{ticketId}
AND
    TICKET_ITEM_VOID = 0]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="TICKET_ITEM_ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_ITEM_DESC" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_CUSTOMER_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_TOTAL_TAX" class="java.lang.Double">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="15per" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL}-$F{TICKET_TOTAL_TAX})*0.15]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="18per" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL}-$F{TICKET_TOTAL_TAX})*0.18]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="20per" class="java.lang.Double">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL}-$F{TICKET_TOTAL_TAX})*0.20]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="count" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{item_name_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{item_name_COUNT}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="item_name">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="f2cebdf8-f1d6-413f-9c03-914be928988c" x="0" y="20" width="195" height="0"/>
                <subreportParameter name="top">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[1]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/ticket_lines.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ffbd8a47-40c3-4210-8301-913b3ef152e6" x="0" y="0" width="195" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{isSale}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NOT A SALE TICKET]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="36">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="a1231c58-cd4f-46d7-87ce-a277abb52bc6" x="0" y="0" width="195" height="36">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_CUSTOMER_NAME} == null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="ticketId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ticketId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/details.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="f47b2daf-b879-4fd6-9168-f1893a5a323f" x="0" y="0" width="195" height="36">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_CUSTOMER_NAME} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="ticketId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ticketId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/customerDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="11" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="11" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5b3ae499-3805-43ed-8f73-5a07bb67d2be" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="20" y="0" width="140" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" printWhenGroupChanges="item_name"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="9" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_ITEM_DESC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="16aac7b5-9688-4a78-860a-073cfca5fb9e" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="160" y="0" width="35" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" printWhenGroupChanges="item_name"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="9" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="95f2a214-786a-45f7-ad12-2fc2befb5351" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="11" width="195" height="0" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="TICKET_ITEM_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{TICKET_ITEM_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/modifiers.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" evaluationTime="Group" evaluationGroup="item_name" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="0536d26c-7ce5-4cb6-a3ea-7a8f3303ac25" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="11" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" printWhenGroupChanges="item_name"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri" size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{item_name_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="160">
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement uuid="7fc03f4a-fc6e-486f-8194-c7e6f770f5ff" positionType="Float" x="0" y="59" width="195" height="0" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="top">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[0]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/ticket_lines.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement uuid="3dffcb5c-fda5-483e-a8e6-d584d2343dc6" x="0" y="0" width="195" height="0" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="ticketId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ticketId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/totals.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="64e108d9-e944-402d-b5a4-83c618f64521" positionType="Float" x="0" y="68" width="195" height="92" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="ticketId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ticketId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/deliveryDetails.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement uuid="6757917e-b848-4d29-ad8b-7df6ef333561" positionType="Float" x="0" y="15" width="195" height="0" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="ticketId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ticketId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreports/condensed_transactions.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="f309bce5-1d1b-475f-b6e0-91d254b20ae4" positionType="Float" x="95" y="15" width="55" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{15per}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="67bd8b7a-122e-435f-abf5-e7a109c4f7b8" positionType="Float" x="61" y="41" width="34" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[20% -]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="69ee0f5f-378d-4fa0-b3f5-bd1dc337d71c" positionType="Float" x="61" y="28" width="34" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[18% -]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="1747abc9-812c-4157-a717-fc6774fb92d7" positionType="Float" x="95" y="28" width="55" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{18per}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="ec57b3a8-4b29-40e5-b05c-1b90cab7558f" positionType="Float" x="95" y="41" width="55" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{20per}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8130693f-ca43-4a22-9b05-6f89707dc71f" positionType="Float" x="61" y="15" width="34" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{endTicket}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Calibri"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[15% -]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

What we're looking at is the $V{item_name_COUNT} field. Even with Print Repeated Values set to false, I'm still getting them. Evaluation Time is set to Group because if it's set to anything else, the count will increment and will not give me the correct group count. Any idea how to fix this? I NEED the count.

Comment: Does your query prints not duplicate record when you run outside jasper report

Comment: My query prints all values, so that I can retain the count variable that JasperReports gives me. @Yubi Not entirely sure exactly what you were suggesting, but I revised my sql and fixed the issue.

Comment: oh! thats Great!!! then how did you solved ?

Comment: I changed the query. I posted the updated one in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple GROUP BY and COUNT fixed the issue.

Here's the SQL I used:

```
SELECT
    t.TICKET_ITEM_ID,
    TICKET_ITEM_DESC,
    TICKET_ITEM_TOTAL,
    ticket.TICKET_ID,
    TICKET_CUSTOMER_NAME,
    TICKET_CHECK_TOTAL,
    TICKET_TOTAL_TAX,
    TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER,
    COUNT(TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER) AS COUNT
FROM
    ticket_item AS t,
    ticket
WHERE
    t.TICKET_ID = $P{ticketId}
AND
    ticket.TICKET_ID = $P{ticketId}
AND
    TICKET_ITEM_VOID = 0
GROUP BY
    TICKET_ITEM_NUMBER
```

Everything else stayed the same.